# Replace chars in string with array value

Tags: php

I have the following array

```
static public $tabla = array(
            'A'=>2, 'B'=>2, 'C'=>2,
            'D'=>3, 'E'=>3, 'F'=>3,
            'G'=>4, 'H'=>4, 'I'=>4,
            'J'=>5, 'K'=>5, 'L'=>5,
            'M'=>6, 'N'=>6, 'O'=>6,
            'P'=>7, 'Q'=>7, 'R'=>7,
            'S'=>8, 'T'=>8, 'U'=>8,
            'V'=>9, 'W'=>9, 'X'=>9,
            'Y'=>0, 'Z'=>0
            );
```

And several strings consisting of alphanumeric characters, for example: "**G20513F4561B**".
What is most efficient way of replacing the non-numeric characters in string by its equivalence according the given array?

I know this can be easily implemented using a loop but maybe there is some kind of regular expression that does the trick.

Thanks

Comment: I think you've almost written a regular expression to do what you want. Replace this with this, replace this with this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `strtr()`:

```
echo strtr($str, self::$tabla);
```

Keys will be replaced with their corresponding values.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that very easily with [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), which accepts arrays as its first and second arguments:

```
echo str_replace(array_keys($tabla), array_values($tabla), $str);
```

This creates one array containing all the keys from the original array and another containing all the values. The elements are in corresponding positions according to the order of the original array. When `str_replace` is called with array arguments, the string in the first element of the first array is replaced by the first element of the second array, and so on.